# runtime error when start() called in python

Tags: python, multithreading, runtime

```
def maxpackages():

    while max_packages:

        print("maxpackages")
        # Loop to send amount from config file of msg to server
        for x in range(parser.getint('MaximumPackages', 'MaximumPackages')):
            msg = 'maxpackages'
            mp = multiprocessing.Process(target=sock.sendto, args=(msg.encode(), server_address))
            mp.start()
        resp, server = sock.recvfrom(4096)
        server_resp = resp.decode()
        print(server_resp)
        sock.close()
        break
```

error message:
RuntimeError: 
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

```
    This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
    child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
    in the main module:

        if __name__ == '__main__':
            freeze_support()
            ...

    The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
    is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
```

Comment: How do you call `maxpackages`? Do you put your top level code inside of a `if __name__ == '__main__':` block? On Windows, python runs a child python process that imports your main script. Any code not protected by that `if` is run a second time, essentially re-running your entire application.

Comment: You can read about it at https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#the-spawn-and-forkserver-start-methods

Comment: is this the case on mac as-well?

Comment: No, not by default. You could call `multiprocessing.get_start_method` - if its "spawn" or "forkserver", its a problem. If you call `set_start_method` with one of those, its a problem too. Otherwise, the default on Mac is `fork` and you shouldn't have this re-run on import problem.